# SQL TABLE UPDATE from different source table

Tags: sql

I have a target table which need to be updated as it is used as a history table. For every year it used for update, whenever a new record comes in it has to updated with three columns. If it has a duplicate record it has to be updated with relation to its old record. The record has a column end and start date, so these need to be updated and also for duplicate record, the end date should be delimited.

The column in my target table should be updated is named as ZAH_RES_ID which has values in my source table RES. TO extract these RES_ID's I have a condition, that it has to be retrieved used a set of columns. This criteria set is generally followed by production team, so they use this criteria and update records belongs to that criteria.

I suppose functions would make a best solution for this but I have no idea.

Comment: Which database server and version are you using?

Comment: its not just that update need to add some more things in that